Excel lookup/match bug - can find given but not calculated value, even if they're the same
I'm experiencing a very odd behaviour with Excel lookups and match: if I try a lookup or match for 7.03, it will find a cell, but if I lookup 7.02+0.01, it fails. For example:




A
B




1
7.01
a


2
7.02
b


3
7.03
c


4
7.04
d


5
7.05
e




If I use =VLOOKUP(7.03, A1:B5, 2, 0) it correctly returns c
If I do =VLOOKUP(7.01+0.01,A1:B5, 2, 0), it correctly returns b - it's looking up 7.02
If I do =VLOOKUP(7.02+0.01,A1:B5,2,0) it FAILS and returns #N/A - it also fails for equivalent XLOOKUP and MATCH formulae

It also fails on other calculated values - not just this one. If I do an 'inexact' match type, it finds the wrong value (7.02).
I can work around this, but is this a bug or can I control for it - how!?
I'm on Excel for Mac Version 16.84 (24041420)

Calculations involving numbers with decimal fractions can always produce small differences in value, because such numbers generally have infinite binary expansions that are subject to rounding.
Therefore, if possible, this type of search should be done using integers, or rounding can be used
=VLOOKUP(ROUND(7.02+0.01,2),A1:B5,2,0)

